Studying trigonometry for game dev, have a working Asteroids style vector that rotates 360°, but something confuses me
Let us say I have a magnitude [8] and direction [$97.4°$ or $1.7\pi$], in a unit circle.
I want to "get to" this point in the coordinate plane, to draw the Asteroids ship, but I know I can only modify the '$x$' and '$y$' positions of the ship to get there.
By using trigonometry -- the study of how the sides and angles of a right triangle relate -- and turning the vector into a right triangle, I could solve for the opposite and adjacent using SOHCAHTOA
What confuses me is that after creating this right triangle, the angle doesn't visually appear to be $97.4°$. I am extremely confused by this. If the ship is rotating $360°$ perfectly, and I am inputting $97.4°$ into the cosine or sine functions, shouldn't this angle be obtuse?


If you [edit] the question to show us just what you "input" to $\sin$ and $\cos$ and what comes out that puzzles you we may be able to help. Make sure you are using radians if that's what your code calls for.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

notably, the numbers all make sense to me. I am also using radians in my code! What doesn't make sense to me is purely the visual presentation of the right triangle, because i'm expecting the angle of it to look 97.4°

Are you expecting the right triangle to have a 97.4 degree angle in it?  Because that would be too many degrees for one triangle to have.  In the normal setup, this angle would end up in the northwest (just a bit west of north), but if you draw a right triangle with a negative x and positive y, that triangle will have the supplementary angle in it instead.

Right! over 180 degrees... And the position of the right triangle makes sense. I'm a little confused about why i'm inputting 97.4 degrees then, as the theta of the right triangle? i was under the impression that whatever value you input into sin() [97.4°] should find a home inside the right triangle i'm solving for

What kind of a weird animal is a SOHCAHTOA? :-)

$1.7\pi$ radians is a lot more than $97.4$ degrees.

So the name of this is polar coordinates, if that helps you find more details in the reference of your choice; but the idea is that the angle specifies the direction to your ship from the central pole---0 corresponds to "right", and positive rotation is rotating counterclockwise from there. That means 90°/$\frac{\pi}{2}$ will then correspond to "up", 180°/$\pi$ to "left", etc.
So your 97.4° corresponds to the rotation from "right" to the direction where your ship is, and then the magnitude 8 tells you how far to go in that direction to actually get to your ship's position.  You can see by drawing it out on graph paper that you are into the northwest quadrant compared to your origin/pole, which is why your computer or calculator is telling you that $\cos(97.4°)$ is negative, since that $x$-coordinate would be negative.
The interpretation of sine and cosine as ratios obviously fails for angles past $\frac{\pi}{2}$, so drawing triangles is maybe not helpful; the usual first extension people see is the unit circle one---we define sine and cosine for all angles by saying that the point on the unit circle at an angle $\theta$ is given by $(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$; it works for the angles we already know from right triangles and continues it nicely for bigger angles.

thank you for the exhaustive reply! :) i was confused about the fact that positive rotation is counterclockwise from 0°. Another thing, in game dev the "y" axis of the polar coordinate plane is inverted. i still honestly don't understand why the right triangle of 97.4° would look acute, i know mathematically it makes sense, but ya i think if the angle is obtuse [97.4°] then the right triangle it's inside of should have an obtuse angle too. but i'll study polar coordinates to find that answer!

Well, as mentioned above by several of us, you're never getting an obtuse angle inside a right triangle, and once you get past 180° you're never getting that angle into a triangle at all!  (Maybe considering where your ship is going to be located once you have a direction angle of say 240° might get you past this whole triangle thing.)

It's impossible to have an obtuse angle inside a right angle triangle.
One of the angles is compulsorily $90°$. This means that by sum of angles property, other two angles should add upto $90°$ too, because sum of internal angles$=180°$.
If you put the angle as obtuse, you're exceeding $180°$ if you add them, which isn't possible.
